# Larger GLSL fragment output without mutliple buffer attachments

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader, fbo

Is there any way to emit more then eg. 4 bytes from an GLSL fragment shader, if the implementation doesn't support multiple FBO buffer attachments or 'deep' buffer formats?

For example when using WebGL or OpenGL ES, being restricted to a RGBA output per fragment makes complex calculations extremely inefficient, if parts of the calculations have to be repeated in multiple passes to get more output channels.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, there is no way efficiently output more then the usual channels. That means calculations with more outputs need to be done in more than one pass. Calculations with more than one output that share costly intermediate results may have the intermediate results computed as additional passes before, however the overhead will most likely eat up any performance advantage gained.

Answer (score 1):

What you output isn't measured in bytes, but in *components*. Each image can only store four components, therefore you can only output four components per output image.

If your hardware *could* output more data, then it would allow you to output to more images. It could expose that through an extension. If such an extension is not present, then the hardware can't, and therefore you can't either.

Note that NVIDIA has [such an extension](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/NV/GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments.txt), so their ES enabled hardware might be able to do it.

Comment: That is not a pure hardware issue, for example WebGL only exposes a subset of the features my system sees when using Desktop OpenGL, and this may even change between browsers.

Comment: @dronus: Yes, which is why you have to use *extensions*. WebGL 1.0 only exposes the base minimum functionality; if hardware can do more, it is up to those implementations to expose the appropriate extensions to get at it. Personally, I don't see why they didn't just make it a queriable limit like in GL 3.0 or EXT_FBO...

Comment: On the other hand, for computational needs im not so interested what 'components' a buffer has (like RGB or depth) but how much bytes I can emit from the shader in total, because I can allways pack and unpack the data from one component representation to another as a last resort.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will do a small survey on the exposed extensions now and see if they match among browsers and the desktop driver. Guess that needs to be checked for a lot of platforms then..

Comment: None of some platforms I have tried supports an extension for multiple attachments.

Comment: @dronus: Then you can't do it.

Comment: Yes. And even if I found some that would not be enough to do it. However, it still hard to find a efficent way of mangling my calculations to not use a wider output. The only way seems to split up the calculations to smaller single-output parts and use that in further passes, hoping that outperforms less passes with more re-calcalculation of multiple use values.